# Postfix sending spam to local email addresses without authenticating

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, spam

Running on Centos 6.4. Past two weeks I've been receiving emails from other email accounts located on our server. admin@site.com is sending to careers@site.com and nonexistentemail@site.com is sending to careers@site.com . They all contain a zip file. Emails recently started coming in from admin@subdomain.site.com (site doesn't even have subdomains).

I monitor the server fairly closely and haven't seen any breaches to FTP, SSH or php codes.

The emails appear to come externally from Turkey and other middle east locations. No spam is being sent OUT of the server, they're only being sent and delivered locally.

I thought I had it set to authenticate all users,but it's not authenticating and still sending. Can someone shed some light on what to do or change?

Here are some outtakes of postfix/main.cf file.

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/32
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/site.com.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file= /etc/pki/tls/certs/mycert.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile= /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/spool/postfix/smtpd_tls_cache
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
#non_smtpd_milters =
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
milter_default_action = accept (dkim stuff)
milter_protocol = 2
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail (this is used for having smart mailboxes, so I could group stuff in Mac mail)
```

Here is /var/logs/maillog

```
Mar 20 09:04:09 server1 postfix/smtpd[616]: connect from unknown[62.169.228.29]
Mar 20 09:04:13 server1 postfix/smtpd[616]: disconnect from unknown[62.169.228.29]
Mar 20 09:07:33 server1 postfix/anvil[618]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:62.169.228.29) at Mar 20 09:04:09
Mar 20 09:07:33 server1 postfix/anvil[618]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:62.169.228.29) at Mar 20 09:04:09
Mar 20 09:07:33 server1 postfix/anvil[618]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Mar 20 09:04:09
Mar 20 09:26:45 server1 postfix/smtpd[645]: connect from unknown[125.209.5.163]
Mar 20 09:26:46 server1 postfix/smtpd[645]: disconnect from unknown[125.209.5.163]
Mar 20 09:30:06 server1 postfix/anvil[647]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:125.209.5.163) at Mar 20 09:26:45
Mar 20 09:30:06 server1 postfix/anvil[647]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:125.209.5.163) at Mar 20 09:26:45
Mar 20 09:30:06 server1 postfix/anvil[647]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Mar 20 09:26:45
Mar 20 09:31:21 server1 postfix/smtpd[654]: connect from unknown[31.184.198.210]
Mar 20 09:31:21 server1 postfix/smtpd[654]: setting up TLS connection from unknown[31.184.198.210]
Mar 20 09:31:22 server1 postfix/smtpd[654]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[31.184.198.210]: TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA (128/128 bits)
Mar 20 09:31:22 server1 postfix/smtpd[654]: lost connection after STARTTLS from unknown[31.184.198.210]
Mar 20 09:31:22 server1 postfix/smtpd[654]: disconnect from unknown[31.184.198.210]
Mar 20 09:34:42 server1 postfix/anvil[656]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (submission:31.184.198.210) at Mar 20 09:31:21
Mar 20 09:34:42 server1 postfix/anvil[656]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (submission:31.184.198.210) at Mar 20 09:31:21
Mar 20 09:34:42 server1 postfix/anvil[656]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Mar 20 09:31:21
Mar 20 11:06:44 server1 postfix/smtpd[804]: warning: 185.100.64.70: hostname ip.hoster.kz verification failed: Name or service not known
Mar 20 11:06:44 server1 postfix/smtpd[804]: connect from unknown[185.100.64.70]
Mar 20 11:06:45 server1 postfix/smtpd[804]: disconnect from unknown[185.100.64.70]
Mar 20 11:10:05 server1 postfix/anvil[806]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:185.100.64.70) at Mar 20 11:06:44
Mar 20 11:10:05 server1 postfix/anvil[806]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:185.100.64.70) at Mar 20 11:06:44
Mar 20 11:10:05 server1 postfix/anvil[806]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Mar 20 11:06:44
Mar 20 11:10:09 server1 postfix/smtpd[813]: connect from unknown[31.184.198.210]
Mar 20 11:10:09 server1 postfix/smtpd[813]: setting up TLS connection from unknown[31.184.198.210]
Mar 20 11:10:10 server1 postfix/smtpd[813]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[31.184.198.210]: TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA (128/128 bits)
Mar 20 11:10:10 server1 postfix/smtpd[813]: lost connection after STARTTLS from unknown[31.184.198.210]
Mar 20 11:10:10 server1 postfix/smtpd[813]: disconnect from unknown[31.184.198.210]
Mar 20 11:13:30 server1 postfix/anvil[815]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (submission:31.184.198.210) at Mar 20 11:10:09
Mar 20 11:13:30 server1 postfix/anvil[815]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (submission:31.184.198.210) at Mar 20 11:10:09
Mar 20 11:13:30 server1 postfix/anvil[815]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Mar 20 11:10:09
Mar 20 13:44:46 server1 postfix/smtpd[1023]: warning: 89.248.162.178: address not listed for hostname no-reverse-dns-configured.com
Mar 20 13:44:46 server1 postfix/smtpd[1023]: connect from unknown[89.248.162.178]
Mar 20 13:44:47 server1 postfix/smtpd[1023]: disconnect from unknown[89.248.162.178]
```

Here is an email that came through, which was spam.

```
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 postfix/smtpd[20712]: connect from unknown[203.82.37.180]
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 postfix/smtpd[20712]: 65EE53800A8: client=unknown[203.82.37.180]
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 postfix/cleanup[20717]: 65EE53800A8: message-id=<6520A3B7.5A9.170FCA74038C.copier@mysite.com>
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 opendkim[1444]: 65EE53800A8: [203.82.37.180] [203.82.37.180] not internal
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 opendkim[1444]: 65EE53800A8: not authenticated
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 opendkim[1444]: 65EE53800A8: no signature data
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 postfix/qmgr[27235]: 65EE53800A8: from=<copier@mysite.com>, size=5709, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] at port 49602
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: setuid to spamd succeeded
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: creating default_prefs: /var/log/spamassassin/.spamassassin/user_prefs
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 spamd[19157]: config: cannot create user preferences file /var/log/spamassassin/.spamassassin/user_prefs: No such file or directory
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: failed to create readable default_prefs: /var/log/spamassassin/.spamassassin/user_prefs
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: processing message <6520A3B7.5A9.170FCA74038C.copier@mysite.com> for spamd:492
Mar 22 12:15:20 server1 postfix/smtpd[20712]: disconnect from unknown[203.82.37.180]
Mar 22 12:15:24 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: clean message (7.4/8.0) for spamd:492 in 3.4 seconds, 5621 bytes.
Mar 22 12:15:24 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: result: . 7 - RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET,RCVD_IN_PSBL,RCVD_IN_RP_RNBL,RDNS_NONE,SPF_FAIL,TO_EQ_FM_DOM_SPF_FAIL,TVD_SPACE_RATIO scantime=3.4,size=5621,user=spamd,uid=492,required_score=8.0,rhost=localhost,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=49602,mid=<6520A3B7.5A9.170FCA74038C.copier@mysite.com>,autolearn=no
Mar 22 12:15:24 server1 postfix/pickup[20696]: 3B5CA3800B1: uid=492 from=<copier@mysite.com>
Mar 22 12:15:24 server1 postfix/pipe[20718]: 65EE53800A8: to=<guy.wan@mysite.com>, relay=spamassassin, delay=3.8, delays=0.39/0.01/0/3.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
Mar 22 12:15:24 server1 postfix/qmgr[27235]: 65EE53800A8: removed
Mar 22 12:15:24 server1 postfix/cleanup[20717]: 3B5CA3800B1: message-id=<6520A3B7.5A9.170FCA74038C.copier@mysite.com>
Mar 22 12:15:24 server1 opendkim[1444]: 3B5CA3800B1: DKIM-Signature field added (s=default, d=mysite.com)
Mar 22 12:15:24 server1 spamd[19156]: prefork: child states: II
Mar 22 12:15:24 server1 postfix/qmgr[27235]: 3B5CA3800B1: from=<copier@mysite.com>, size=6120, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 22 12:15:24 server1 postfix/local[20723]: 3B5CA3800B1: to=<guy.wan@mysite.com>, relay=local, delay=0.1, delays=0.06/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/bin/procmail)
Mar 22 12:15:24 server1 postfix/qmgr[27235]: 3B5CA3800B1: removed
Mar 22 12:18:41 server1 postfix/anvil[20714]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:203.82.37.180) at Mar 22 12:15:20
Mar 22 12:18:41 server1 postfix/anvil[20714]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:203.82.37.180) at Mar 22 12:15:20
Mar 22 12:18:41 server1 postfix/anvil[20714]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Mar 22 12:15:20
Mar 22 12:44:56 server1 postfix/smtpd[20796]: connect from unknown[181.198.236.222]

Mar 22 15:49:54 server1 postfix/smtpd[21823]: connect from unknown[181.65.123.194]
Mar 22 15:49:54 server1 postfix/smtpd[21823]: A9B073800A8: client=unknown[181.65.123.194]
Mar 22 15:49:55 server1 postfix/cleanup[21828]: A9B073800A8: message-id=<cead305f488188dfc8cfcf6774e7643b@localhost.localdomain>
Mar 22 15:49:55 server1 opendkim[1444]: A9B073800A8: [181.65.123.194] [181.65.123.194] not internal
Mar 22 15:49:55 server1 opendkim[1444]: A9B073800A8: not authenticated
Mar 22 15:49:55 server1 opendkim[1444]: A9B073800A8: no signature data
Mar 22 15:49:55 server1 postfix/qmgr[27235]: A9B073800A8: from=<voicemailandfax@surevoip.com>, size=6734, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 22 15:49:55 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] at port 50409
Mar 22 15:49:55 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: setuid to spamd succeeded
Mar 22 15:49:55 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: creating default_prefs: /var/log/spamassassin/.spamassassin/user_prefs
Mar 22 15:49:55 server1 spamd[19157]: config: cannot create user preferences file /var/log/spamassassin/.spamassassin/user_prefs: No such file or directory
Mar 22 15:49:55 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: failed to create readable default_prefs: /var/log/spamassassin/.spamassassin/user_prefs
Mar 22 15:49:55 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: processing message <cead305f488188dfc8cfcf6774e7643b@localhost.localdomain> for spamd:492
Mar 22 15:49:55 server1 postfix/smtpd[21823]: disconnect from unknown[181.65.123.194]
Mar 22 15:49:56 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: clean message (6.9/8.0) for spamd:492 in 1.1 seconds, 6629 bytes.
Mar 22 15:49:56 server1 spamd[19157]: spamd: result: . 6 - HTML_MESSAGE,RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET,RCVD_IN_BRBL_LASTEXT,RCVD_IN_PSBL,RDNS_NONE,URIBL_BLOCKED scantime=1.1,size=6629,user=spamd,uid=492,required_score=8.0,rhost=localhost,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=50409,mid=<cead305f488188dfc8cfcf6774e7643b@localhost.localdomain>,autolearn=no
Mar 22 15:49:56 server1 postfix/pickup[21711]: 41F7E3800B1: uid=492 from=<voicemailandfax@surevoip.com>
Mar 22 15:49:56 server1 postfix/pipe[21829]: A9B073800A8: to=<advertising@mysite.com>, relay=spamassassin, delay=1.6, delays=0.4/0.01/0/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
Mar 22 15:49:56 server1 postfix/qmgr[27235]: A9B073800A8: removed
Mar 22 15:49:56 server1 postfix/cleanup[21828]: 41F7E3800B1: message-id=<cead305f488188dfc8cfcf6774e7643b@localhost.localdomain>
Mar 22 15:49:56 server1 opendkim[1444]: 41F7E3800B1: no signing table match for 'voicemailandfax@surevoip.com'
Mar 22 15:49:56 server1 opendkim[1444]: 41F7E3800B1: no signature data
Mar 22 15:49:56 server1 postfix/qmgr[27235]: 41F7E3800B1: from=<voicemailandfax@surevoip.com>, size=7129, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 22 15:49:56 server1 spamd[19156]: prefork: child states: II
Mar 22 15:49:56 server1 postfix/local[21834]: 41F7E3800B1: to=<advertising@mysite.com>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/bin/procmail)
Mar 22 15:49:56 server1 postfix/qmgr[27235]: 41F7E3800B1: removed
```

Comment: The connecting IP `203.82.37.180` seems to be in `Spamhaus` [CBL](http://www.abuseat.org/lookup.cgi?ip=203.82.37.180) You can use RBLs to block most of the spam.

Comment: Thanks clement, after you mentioned this I found some stuff that blacklists them. Hopefully the solution Aaron gave will work out. I have a feeling SASL configs might've been setup wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to implement Sender Policy Framework in postfix and to add an SPF record to your domain.

Postfix Implimentation:

1. Install spf package: `sudo apt-get install postfix-policyd-spf-perl`
2. Modify main.cf:

Add Anywhere:
`policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s`

Add to smtpd_recipient_restrictions:
`check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf`

3. Modify master

Add:

`policy-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       -       spawn
     user=nobody argv=/usr/sbin/postfix-policyd-spf-perl`

4. Reload postfix: `service postfix reload`

[Wizard for creating SPF record for your domain](http://www.spfwizard.net/) (*Will require basic understanding of how to add domain dns records*).

Comment: Thanks for this. I did this and did some other things and messed up my postfix config lol. This is likely the right answer, but just trying to get it up right now and attempt to do that again.